# Error: "this class is not key value coding-compliant" - for any key

Tags: swift, core-data

I am saving an object in a Core Data model, but I am getting that the key is not coding-compliant for any key.

I tried invert the orders of the keys, but I am getting for any of that, I tried to change the nome o entity but not worked too.

```
        let mediaEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: 
"Media", in: managedContext)
        mediaEntity?.setValue(showMediaModel.popularity, forKey: "popularity")
        mediaEntity?.setValue(showMediaModel.title, forKey: "title")
        mediaEntity?.setValue(showMediaModel.type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
        mediaEntity?.setValue(showMediaModel.id, forKey: "id")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

The core data model:

[image: core data model]

The detailed message error is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<NSEntityDescription 0x6000008c02c0> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding- 
compliant for the key popularity.'
```

I added the core data after start the project by following this tutorial: https://welcm.uk/blog/adding-core-data-to-an-existing-project-in-xcode-10-swift-4

Comment: I forgot that I add into the NSManagedObject, not on NSEntityDescription. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `xcdatamodel` file and make sure your spelling of "popularity" matches with the spelling in the line that is giving the error.

Comment: It is not working for any key, I checked the name of each one.

Answer (score -2):

I forgot to create the object.

```
if let mediaEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Media", in: managedContext) {
    let newEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: mediaEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
    newEntity.setValue(showMediaModel.popularity, forKey: "popularity")
    newEntity.setValue(showMediaModel.title, forKey: "title")
    newEntity.setValue(showMediaModel.type.rawValue, forKey: "type")
    newEntity.setValue(showMediaModel.id, forKey: "id")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```